# JOIN 2 Tables with different columns

Tags: php, mysql

I Have 2 Tables, One For New Pictures and One For New Users, i want to create like a wall that mixes the latest actions so it'll show new users & pictures ordered by date.

What i want is a single query and how to know inside the loop that the current entry is a photo or user.

```
TABLE: users
Columns: id,username,fullname,country,date

TABLE: photos
Columns: id,picurl,author,date
```

Desired Output:

---

**Daniel** from **California** Has just registred *5mins ago*

---

New Picture By **David** ( click to view ) *15mins ago*

---

And so on...

I'm begging you to not just give me the query syntax, i'm not pro and can't figure out how to deal with that inside the loop ( i only know how to fetch regular sql queries )

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use an union:

```
SELECT concat(username, " from ", country, " has just registered") txt, date FROM users
UNION
SELECT concat("New picture By ", username, " (click to view)") txt, date FROM photos INNER JOIN users ON author=users.id
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This assumes that `author` column in `photos` corresponds to the `users` table `id`. If author actually is a string containing the user name (which is a bad design), you'll have to do this instead:

```
SELECT concat(username, " from ", country, " has just registered") txt, date FROM users
UNION
SELECT concat("New picture By ", author, " (click to view)") txt, date FROM photos
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Make sure you have an index on `date` in both tables, or this will be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together this little example for you to look at - you might find it helpful.

Full script can be found here : http://pastie.org/1279954

So it starts with 3 simple tables countries, users and user_photos.

**Tables**

*Note: i've only included the minimum number of columns for this demo to work !*

```
drop table if exists countries;
create table countries
(
country_id tinyint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
iso_code varchar(3) unique not null,
name varchar(255) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
country_id tinyint unsigned not null,
username varbinary(32) unique not null
-- all other detail omitted
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists user_photos;
create table user_photos
(
photo_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
user_id int unsigned not null,
-- all other detail omitted
key (user_id)
)
engine=innodb;
```

The important thing to note is that the primary keys of users and photos are unsigned integers and auto_increment (1,2,3..n) so I can find the latest 10 users and 10 photos by ordering by their primary keys (PK) descending and add a limit clause to restrict the number of rows returned.

```
-- change limit to increase rows returned
select * from users order by user_id desc limit 2; 
select * from user_photos order by photo_id desc limit 2;
```

**Test Data**

```
insert into countries (iso_code, name) values ('GB','Great Britain'),('US','United States'),('DE','Germany');

insert into users (username, country_id) values ('f00',1),('bar',2),('stack',1),('overflow',3);

insert into user_photos (user_id) values (1),(1),(2),(3),(1),(4),(2),(1),(4),(2),(1);
```

So now we need a convenient way (single call) of selecting the latest 10 users and photos. The two tables are completely different so a union isnt going to be the best approach so what we'll do instead is write a stored procedure that returns two resultsets and handle generating the wall (merge resultsets) in our php script.

**Stored procedure**

Just a wrapper around some SQL code - think of it like SQL's version of a function call

```
drop procedure if exists list_latest_users_and_photos;

delimiter #

create procedure list_latest_users_and_photos()
begin

-- last 10 users
select 
    'U' as type_id, -- integer might be better
     u.user_id,
     u.country_id,
     u.username,
     -- other user columns...
     c.name as country_name
from 
 users u 
inner join countries c on u.country_id = c.country_id
order by 
 u.user_id desc limit 10;

-- last 10 photos

select 
 'P' as type_id, 
 up.photo_id,
 up.user_id,
 -- other photo columns...
 u.username 
 -- other user columns...
from 
 user_photos up
inner join users u on up.user_id = u.user_id
order by
 up.photo_id desc limit 10;

end #

delimiter ;
```

**Testing**

To test our stored procedure all we need to do is call it and look at the results.

```
mysql> call list_latest_users_and_photos();

+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+
| type_id | user_id | country_id | username | country_name  |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+
| U       |       4 |          3 | overflow | Germany       |
| U       |       3 |          1 | stack    | Great Britain |
| U       |       2 |          2 | bar      | United States |
| U       |       1 |          1 | f00      | Great Britain |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| type_id | photo_id | user_id | username |
+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| P       |       11 |       1 | f00      |
| P       |       10 |       2 | bar      |
| P       |        9 |       4 | overflow |
| P       |        8 |       1 | f00      |
| P       |        7 |       2 | bar      |
| P       |        6 |       4 | overflow |
| P       |        5 |       1 | f00      |
| P       |        4 |       3 | stack    |
| P       |        3 |       2 | bar      |
| P       |        2 |       1 | f00      |
+---------+----------+---------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now we know that works we can call it from php and generate the wall.

**PHP Script**

```
<?php

$conn = new Mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db");

$result = $conn->query("call list_latest_users_and_photos()");

$users = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $users[] = $row;

$conn->next_result();
$result = $conn->use_result();

$photos = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $photos[] = $row;

$result->close();   
$conn->close();

$wall = array_merge($users, $photos);

echo "<pre>", print_r($wall), "</pre>";

?>
```

Hope you find some of this helpful :)